# Cut and Paste from 4x2 table Into One Row

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with answers to questions for an exam. It is set up as a series of 4x2 blocks. Each block has the 4 multiple choice answers in the first column, and then a 0 or a 1 in the column to the right indicating correct or incorrect.

I want to make a macro to take the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th answer and corresponding 0/1 cell and paste them so they end up to the right of the 1st answer in the block. I have this macro so far, which successfully edits the first answer and correctness indicator column:

```
Range("A2:B2").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3:B3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A4:B4").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("G1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

How can I change it so that it will do cells 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, etc. but skip 1, 5, 9, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: First you are going to want to start from the bottom because you are going to be deleting rows.  Also [NEVER USE SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the columns into a text editor and using regex to do the work, as that was a much simpler way of doing it. I searched for blocks of 4 lines and replaced returns with tabs where appropriate so it would fit on one line and go back into Excel easily.

Comment: Seems counter-productive.  I didn't see any comments on my answer why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input of:

[image]

Using code:

```
Sub QReform()

Dim CurRow As Long, LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If ((CurRow - 1) / 5) - ((CurRow - 1) \ 5) = 0 Then
        Cells(CurRow, 2).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 3).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 1).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 4).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(2, 0).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 5).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(2, 1).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 6).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(3, 0).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 7).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(3, 1).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 8).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(4, 0).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 9).Value = Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(4, 1).Value
        Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(4, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(3, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        Cells(CurRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Will give you this:

[image]